# How to declare multiple activities in Manifest.xml on Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I am self learner to android.
Right now i have five pages in an android application.The first page contains two buttons(button1,button2).If i trigger the button1 it should go to the second page,which  contains one button,again if i trigger this button finally it should simply display a tab host which laying on the third page.Likewise if i trigger the button2 from the page one it should go to page four and page five as like what the button1 has done.

During at run when i am clicking the button from page four,it shown error message as
**Sorry! The application Tabhost_demo has stopped unexpectedly.please try again!**
(Note : Other Pages activities are working well rather than four and five).

**Refer java class source**

```
public class First_index extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_parent);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Index_parent.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
          }
});
```

This is for page switching right?

---

**AND THIS SOURCE IS FOR TABHOSTING**

```
    public class Parent_concpt extends TabActivity {  
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
        @Override  
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.main3);  

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

            // Tab for Attendance
            TabSpec pho = tabHost.newTabSpec("Attendance");
            // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
            pho.setIndicator("Attendance",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_att_parent));
        Intent phoIntent = new Intent(this, Att_parents.class);
        pho.setContent(phoIntent);

        // Tab for Marks
        TabSpec mrk = tabHost.newTabSpec("Achievement");
        mrk.setIndicator("Achievement",     getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_achieve_parents));
        Intent mrkIntent = new Intent(this, Achieve_parents.class);
        mrk.setContent(mrkIntent);

        // Tab for Fee
        TabSpec fees = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fee details");
            fees.setIndicator("Fee details",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_fee_details));
        Intent feesIntent = new Intent(this, Feedet_parents.class);
        fees.setContent(feesIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(pho);
        tabHost.addTab(mrk);
        tabHost.addTab(fees);}}
```

**My ambigution is,i guess only the problem is on Manifest.xml file.IS THERE ANY PERMISSIONS AVAILABLE TO MENTION FOR EVERY ACTIVITY?**

---

**Refer Manifest.xml source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.demo.student"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity android:name=".First_index"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Index_parent"></activity>


        <activity android:name=".Index_parent"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN1" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Parent_concpt"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".Parent_concept"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN3" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <!--  Att_parents -->
         <activity android:name=".Att_parents" />

         <!--  Achieve_parents -->
         <activity android:name=".Achieve_parents" />

         <!--  Feedet_parents -->
         <activity android:name=".Feedet_parents" />


        <activity android:name=".Index_principal"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN2" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity><activity android:name=".Princy_concept"></activity>

          <activity android:name=".Princy_concept"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN7" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>

         <!--  Att_principal Activity -->
         <activity android:name=".Att_principal" />

         <!--  Perform_principal Activity -->
         <activity android:name=".Perform_principal" />

         <!--  Coll_principal Activity -->
         <activity android:name=".Coll_principal" />

         <!--  Xpense_principal Activity -->
         <activity android:name=".Xpense_principal" />

         </application>
    </manifest>
```

**NOTE :** I have perfectly mentioned each and every class and layout's file name perfectly.

Please refer my logcat here
**LOGCAT**

```
05-21 12:13:16.013: W/KeyCharacterMap(274): No keyboard for id 0
05-21 12:13:16.013: W/KeyCharacterMap(274): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-21 12:13:19.843: D/AndroidRuntime(274): Shutting down VM
05-21 12:13:19.843: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.demo.student/com.android.demo.student.Princy_concept}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:105)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.demo.student.Princy_concept.onCreate(Princy_concept.java:16)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-21 12:13:19.853: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what are your xml files..In your class Parent_concpt you mentioned setContentView(R.layout.main3); Did you create main3.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is telling you that in your layout `main3`, you must have a `TabHost` named `android.R.id.tabhost`

In `onCreate()` you are inflating main3:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main3);
```

Open up main3.xml and make sure your layout looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Note the `TabHost`'s name and the name of the `TabWidget`.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

It's to late to answer this but I guess it may help others.

In your manifest.xml file you need to specify only one Activity as Luncher  Activity which is going to pop up when the app starts.

assigning more than one Activity to be Luncher will trigger `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity` Exception.

so the right way to declare other Activities beside the luncher Activity is by changing its category to Default or other category.

to find more about Intent-filter Categories please go to:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html

and for more readings on manifest.xml file:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.YourActivityName" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />
</intent-filter>
```